# Finding the asymptotic expansion of $\sin(3x)$ using asymptotic sequence $\{\ln(1+x^n)\}_n$

Tags: asymptotics

Finding the asymptotic expansion of $\sin(3x)$ using asymptotic sequence $\{\ln(1+x^n)\}_n$. In the notes and lectures the only example that was given was an expansion for $\tan(x)$ where she literally just swapped the $x$ terms for $sin x$ terms since they are both asymptotic sequences. Is that the case here? Do I just find the regular expansion for $\sin(3x)$ and substitute in the relevant terms from the sequence?

Sorry if this is being confusing. Is this a solution?
Since:
$$\sin(3x)=(3x)-(3x)^3/6+...$$
and
$$\ln(1+x)=x-1/2 x^2+1/3x^3-...,$$ $$\ln(1+x^2)=x^2-1/2x^4+...$$ $$\ln(1+x^3)=x^3$$
We have clearly that $a_1=3$, then $-1/2a_1+a_2=0$ and $1/3a_1+a_3=0$
So:
$$\sin(3x)=3\ln(1+x)+3/2\ln(1+x^2)-\ln(1+x^3)$$?

Comment: Seems like it's the really the case, since $\ln(1+x^n) \approx x^n$ as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @daniel this could be what is meant!

Comment: The substituting $3x$ into the $sin(x)$ expansion was not the bit I was confused about

Comment: I just mentioned it in the case this would have been the case...

Comment: I'm confused by this question. How would one use $\ln(1+x^n)$ to find the series of $\sin(3x)$? Seems very strange. Is that the exact quote of the exercise?

Comment: It's the nature of using asymptotic sequences to relate to functions. We use $x^n$ for convenience but we can use other asymptotic sequences to approximate functions.